# Magento 2: Observer getRequest not working and product added issue

Tags: magento2, cart, event-observer, magento-2.1.4

I have below observer

```
namespace Custom\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class ProductObserver implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $_urlManager;
    protected $_checkoutSession;
    protected $_cart;
    protected $_messageManager;
    protected $_redirect;
    protected $_request;
    protected $_response;
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_resultFactory;
    protected $_scopeConfig;
    protected $_product;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlManager,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession, 
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect, 
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart, 
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager, 
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request, 
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response, 
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig, 
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, 
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory, 
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $resultFactory
    ) {
        $this->_urlManager = $urlManager;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_redirect = $redirect;
        $this->_cart = $cart;
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_response = $response;
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_resultFactory = $resultFactory;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_product = $product;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        
        //$observer->getRequest()->setParam('product', false); // Not working

        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        $postValues = $this->_request->getPostValue();
        $cartQuote = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getData();
        $cartItemsCount = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getItemsCount();
        $cartItemsAll = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

        $this->_request->setParam('product', false); // Will not add product to Cart
        $this->_response->setRedirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        $this->_checkoutSession->setNoCartRedirect(false);
    }
}
```

It gives error on

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setParam() on null in

If I'm using

`$this->_request->setParam('product', false);` // Will not add product to Cart

Then also it adds product to the cart. It should not product to the cart right?

As  `$observer->getRequest()->setParam('product', false);` not working need to use above ones.

Answer (score 1):

You need to Inject  `\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http`
like:

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Something;
class ClassName 
{
    protected $request;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        ....//rest of parameters here
    ) {
       $this->request = $request;
       ...//rest of constructor here
    }
    public function getPost()
    {
        return $this->request->getPost();
    }
}
```

then you can get the values. It should work for you

Comment: By doing `$this->getPost()->setParam('product', false);` still it add product to cart. It gives `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend\Stdlib\Parameters::setParam() `

Comment: Try $this->request->setParam('product', false);

Comment: I already tried seems not working

Answer (score 0):

Refer to http://alanstorm.com/magento_dispatch_standard_router/
After that You should know why setParam is not working like you want.